# Function not Reading ifstream file

Tags: c++

I'm working on code for one of my programming classes and my professor won't allow any of the code to be changed besides that within each function (function arguments and the main function are not allowed to be changed). The issue comes with one of the functions making use of ifstream&.

The issue arises in this specific function, which is supposed to take in the all of the data from the input file (in this case programmers.txt), but the program doesn't read the data from the file at all.

```
int readProgrammers(ifstream& inputFile, Programmer programmers[], int maxProgrammers )
{
    inputFile.open("programmers.txt", std::ios_base::in);

    for (int i = 0; i < maxProgrammers; i++)
    {
        inputFile >> programmers[i].programmer_id;
        inputFile >> programmers[i].name;
        inputFile >> programmers[i].lines;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've messed around with .ignore() as well as quadruple checking whether or not I got the name of the file wrong (which I didn't). I also tried going without using .open inside of the function to see if that was messing around with this, but I ended up with the same exact result. I'm honestly not sure as to what the issue is since I rarely use ifstream& in functions as it usually turns out extremely buggy.

For a little more info so as to help, this is the data within the file that's being read.

```
1 Alvin 300
2 Brenda 350
3 Chris 250
4 Dana 500
5 Eli 450
6 Faye 320
7 Glen 670
8 Hannah 230
9 Ian 420
10 Jade 380
```

I'm supposed to try and store this information into an array Programmer structs. What I'm doing wrong that's causing the file not to be read?

**Edit:**

I got rid of the .open within the function and checked with getLine and cout to see if the file is being read, and it is by getLine, so I'm not sure why the data isn't being stored/read by this code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < maxProgrammers; i++)
    {
        inputFile >> programmers[i].programmer_id;
        inputFile >> programmers[i].name;
        inputFile >> programmers[i].lines;
    }
```

Comment: Don't need `std::ios_base::in`, the `i` in `ifstream` takes care of that. You don't check if the file was opened successfully. If your code to fill out the structs isn't working, you could use `getline` to just read each line and output it to see if you're getting the data you expect.

Comment: What does the Programmer struct/class look like? You should check the input operation to see if it is successful. `if(if >> p.id >> p.name >> p.lines)` or keep it granular like you have but make sure each one is ok. This works, maybe it will give you some ideas. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bbda7f7747de97fb

Answer (score 1):

Don't call `open()` on a `std::ifstream` that is passed in to the function. It should be the caller's responsibility to make sure the stream is open before calling the function. Just read from whatever open stream is given to you.

I suggest you use `std::getline()` to read the input stream a line at a time,  using a `std::istringstream` to read individual values from each line.

Try this:

```
int readProgrammers(ifstream& inputFile, Programmer programmers[], int maxProgrammers)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < maxProgrammers; i++) 
    {
        string line;
        if (!getline(inputFile, line)) break;
        istringstream iss(line);
        iss >> programmers[i].programmer_id;
        iss >> programmers[i].name;
        iss >> programmers[i].lines;
        ++count;
    }
    return count;
}
```

```
ifstream inputFile("programmers.txt");
Programmer programmers[10];
readProgrammers(inputFile, programmers, 10);
```